# how to change Header text into grid view

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 columns 
in code behind i've this :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
        string query = "SELECT ID , NAME FROM PROFITCATEGORIES";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                GridViewCategory.DataSource = rdr;
                GridViewCategory.DataBind();
GridViewCategory.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header text"; // ERROR IS HERE

            }
        }



    }
```

but this give me an error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

error is on this line : GridViewCategory.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header text";

Answer (score 0):

You would have no column in gridview until you bind it to some datasource. Try your code with little change

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
    string query = "SELECT ID , NAME FROM PROFITCATEGORIES";
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {                
            GridViewCategory.DataSource = rdr;
            GridViewCategory.DataBind();
            // Write this line after above two
            GridViewCategory.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header text";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Move it up but stil same error i try it before i miss something else

Answer (score 0):

At the point in the code where you assign data to Columns[0], you have no Columns since you have not bound the GridView yet.  Rearrange the order of your code:

```
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            GridViewCategory.DataSource = rdr;
            GridViewCategory.DataBind();
            If(GridViewCategory.Columns.Any())
               GridViewCategory.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header text";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
    string query = "SELECT ID , NAME FROM PROFITCATEGORIES";
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {                
            GridViewCategory.DataSource = rdr;
            GridViewCategory.DataBind();

            if (GridViewCategory.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                 GridViewCategory.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Header text";
            }

        }
    }
}
```